# WCF - How do I know when a connection is lost from server (service) side? (for ex: client crashes may be because of some fatal exception)

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I am using `NetNamedPipebinding` to communicate between two processes. One of them provides a service at an end point and the other process using `DuplexChannel` communicates with it.

In some scenario my client process might crash. In those scenarios I need to kill the service process as well. What is the best way to achieve it?

From server side:

I am thinking of having a timer and call the ping method on the callback. If client doesn't respond for ping, I can shut down the service as well. Is there any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I am the one who creates the service (process). So I simply passed the process ID of the client process to server (service process) and listen to Process.Exited event.

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~

Comment: Yes please to @Andrew's suggestion - are you able to accept this answer, Dreamer?